# Segmentation fault using arrays of structs

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to make a sorting program in c. Specifically a bucket sort. Anyway, I was entering the values from the original array into my buckets (Canasta) structure, and no matter I've tried I get a segmentation fault error. I also have read another similar questions here and tried what it says but it doesn't work.

Build: gcc sort.c -o sort

Run Test:  $ ./sort 5

**Being 5 the number of buckets that must be created**

**Update: I forgot to comment in this section on which line the error is generated. And I added the missing code.  Thank you.**

Error line 78: `basket[numcan].entrada[acum[numcan]] = lista[i];`

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define MAX 200
#define HOLGURA 50

typedef struct intervalo{
    int inf;
    int sup;
} Intervalo;

typedef struct canasta{
    Intervalo inter;
    int *entrada;
    int size;
} Canasta;

Canasta crearCanasta(Intervalo inter, int size){
    Canasta *basket = NULL;
    basket = (Canasta*)malloc(sizeof(Canasta));
    basket->entrada = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    basket->inter = inter;
    return *basket;
}

int * generarLista(){
    static int lista[MAX];
    time_t t;
    /* Inicializa seed de rand() */
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        lista[i] = rand() % 200; // Random de 0 a 999
        printf("lista: %d. ", lista[i]);
    }
    return lista;
}

int determinarCanasta(Intervalo * inter, int numhilos, int num){
    for(int i = 0; i < numhilos; i++){
        if(num > inter[i].inf && num < inter[i].sup)
            return i;
    }
}

Intervalo * crearIntervalo(int tamArr, int numhilos){
    Intervalo *aux = malloc(numhilos*sizeof(Intervalo));
    aux[0].inf = 0;
    aux[0].sup = tamArr + HOLGURA;
    for (int i = 1; i < numhilos; i++){
        aux[i].inf = tamArr*i + HOLGURA;
        aux[i].sup = tamArr*(i+1) + HOLGURA;
    }
    return aux;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    int *lista = generarLista();
    printf("Paso la generacion de lista\n");
    int salida[MAX];

    if(argv[1] > 0){
        int tamArr = MAX / atoi(argv[1]); // Tamaño maximo del arreglo
        Intervalo *inter = crearIntervalo(tamArr, atoi(argv[1])); // Arreglo de intervalos
        printf("Paso generacion de intervalos\n");
        Canasta *basket = malloc(atoi(argv[1]) * sizeof(Canasta)); // Arreglo de canastas
        printf("Paso asignacion de memoria de canastas\n");
        int numcan = 0;
        int acum[atoi(argv[1])];
        int array[atoi(argv[1])][tamArr + HOLGURA];

        for (int i = 0; i < atoi(argv[1]); i++){
            basket[i] = crearCanasta(inter[i], atoi(argv[1]));
            acum[i] = 0;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
            numcan = determinarCanasta(inter, atoi(argv[1]), lista[i]);
            basket[numcan].entrada[acum[numcan]] = lista[i]; // This line makes the error
            printf("%d. ", numcan);
            // I also tried to make an auxiliary bidimensional array to store the values but I get the same error
            //array[numcan][acum[numcan]] = lista[i];
            acum[numcan]++;
        }

        printf("Paso determinacion de canasta\n");
    
    }
    else{
        printf("ERROR: Ingresa un numero valido de canastas");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help :)

Comment: Do basic debugging. Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately and exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault. That's the minimum info you should know for yourself and to post in the question. The debugger can also be used to step through the code and inspect it as it runs.

Comment: Keep debugging. For example, did you look at the value of `numcan` and `acum[numcan]` when the crash occurs? What values are they and are they within the bounds of the respective arrays?

Comment: It crash for any value of basket[numcan], I've even tried doing something like `basket[0].entrada[acum[numcan]] = lista[i]` and it works, but obviously I need to put every number in the correct bucket. I'm sure that I have reserved the memory for the array of struct `basket`, so I'm very cunfused about this error. Also, I have checked that the values that `determinarCanasta()` returns for numcan are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i saw in the code, the segment fault happens when the `determinarCanasta` function never returns an `i` value in the iteration. It is hard to understand what behavior you expect, but it would find an interval correctly if you change to `if (num >= inter[i].inf && num <= inter[i].sup)` (with `<=` and `>=`). One other solution is to define a default value to be returned in this case.

```
int determinarCanasta(Intervalo * inter, int numhilos, int num){
    for (int i = 0; i < numhilos; i++) {
        if (num >= inter[i].inf && num <= inter[i].sup)
            return i;
    }
    // return some value
    return DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GustavoBiage, I've changed the `determinarCanasta()` function considering the missing value of the interval. And I got rid of the segmentation bug.

Leaving the condition as follows:
`if(num >= inter[i].inf && num < inter[i].sup)`